# How to share common things among par::packer generated exe files?

Tags: windows, perl, activeperl, par

I've just tried to generate *.exe files from Perl scripts by using **Par::Packer**, the tool works fine as expected.

The situation now is I would like to distribute my Perl based application as a group of utilities (exe files), for each of them there is a corresponding Perl scripts, and they are sharing some common modules (including Perl stuff) pretty much. This results in each of the generated *exe files are bloated by similar codes.

I tried to attach --dependency option to **pp**, which reduce the size in some extent, while it just move the perl.dll out of the packaged file, the common modules are still there. I think there should be some other approaches to resolve this.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://cava.co.uk/ provides that out of the box, allows you to easily create a .msi style installer, with however many scripts you want available as .exe files (and all modules and everything else required is shared)

You could also pack [Par::WebStart](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PAR-WebStart/)'s `perlws`, and pack each app using its `make_par`, then invoke each app using  `appshortcut.lnk`  or `appshortcut.bat`, or `appshortcut.exe` which just does `system "perlws.exe appshortcut.pnlp"`

or you could turn all your utilities into modules (you should do that anyway), and then pack them all with `pp` into a single  single .exe, then create 
`foo.exe  bar.exe   baz.exe  ...` which just do `system "mybigexe.exe foo.exe"`

change the icons... with `exe_update` (from cpan)

Comment: cava seems very promising, the other approaches are interesting as well. I'm gonna try all of them then pick one. Thank you.